# Visual Studio - Insert Newline at the End of Files When Saving

Tags: visual-studio

I know that this can easily be done in `vscode`. In visual studio, however, seems there is no other way around installing an [external extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jdforsythe.add-new-line-to-files) that handles it. Is that the case indeed?